# Vegachess pairing software pairing problem

Tags: chess

[Vegachess pairing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BZM5.png)
Hello after i installed the app ,cannot make automatic pairing.Please provide a solution

Comment: Obvious question: do you have Java installed?

Comment: Yes ,Of course !